# jquerymobile positioning box and adding theme

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

Im new to working with   tags and jquery mobile in general, Im trying to make a box just under the header, like this image shows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMza1.jpg

Can someone guide me through it, with the position and everything, and maybe use the theme to make it look good, here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>
    <title>Timesedler</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">

<link href="Connections/small-device.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body> 

<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
            <div data-role="header">
    <div class="header_login">
        Velkommen <a href="edit_account.php"><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a> | <a href="logout.php">Log ud</a>
        </div>
        <h1>Timesedler</h1>

</div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">

<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="sebrugere.php" data-role"button">Se Brugere</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
    <li><a href="tfordre.php" data-role"button">Tilføj Ordre</a></li>
    <li><a href="seordre.php" data-role"button">Se Ordre</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
    <li><a href="tftimer.php" data-role"button">Tilføj Timer</a></li>
    <li><a href="setimer.php" data-role"button">Se Timer</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Copyright © Xplayed.com 2013</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you get stuck? Can you show the CSS you have so far?

Comment: I´m stuck at the start, i have never used <div></div> tags before, so i don´t know where to start with the fixed positioning, or if i have to add it in the header or below the header. I donbt have anyy css apart from the jquery, small-device.css is empty